# How to make an object move towards another object (its food) in processing?

Tags: java, arraylist, processing, simulation

I am trying to simulate a herd of rabbits in a grass field using processing. As I am a beginner, I decided to skip acceleration while moving, that is the rabbits have a constant magnitude of velocity.
Each rabbit has a separation radius in order to keep them separated. For food, I decided to greedily search all the grass objects near me and move towards the closest, however whenever I try to run the program, all the grass objects teleport towards the origin and I can't find the reason for it.

This is the main file.

```
ArrayList<Rabbit> R = new ArrayList<Rabbit>();
ArrayList<Grass> G = new ArrayList<Grass>();
ArrayList<Grass> K = G;
int grass = 25;
int r_Size = 10;
int day = 0;
int i = 0;

void setup(){
 size(1000,8000);
 for(int i = 0;i<r_Size;i++){
   R.add(new Rabbit());
 }
  for(int i = 0;i<grass;i++){
   G.add(new Grass());
 }
}

void draw(){
  background(120);
  i++;
  

  
  for(Grass r : G){
    r.show();
    r.find();
  }
  for(Rabbit r : R){
    r.show();
    r.move();
  }
  
  fill(255);
  text(day,10,100);
  if(i >= 10){
    day++;
    i = 0;
   ArrayList<Grass> d = new ArrayList<Grass>();
   for(Grass g : G){
    if(g.isEaten){
      d.add(g);
    }
   }
   for(Grass g : d){
    G.remove(g); 
   }
  }
  
  if(day >= 30){
   System.out.println(R.size());
   for(Grass r : G){
    r.update();
   }
   for(int i = 0;i<10;i++){
    G.add(new Grass()); 
   }

   ArrayList<Rabbit> dead = new ArrayList<Rabbit>();
   for (Rabbit r : R){
    r.update();
    if(r.isDead == true) 
      dead.add(r);
   }
   for(Rabbit r : dead){
    R.remove(r); 
   }
   day = 0;
  }
}
```

This is the Grass Class.

```
class Grass{
 PVector pos;
 int age = 0;
 int side = 20;
 boolean isEaten = false;
 int perTurn = 10;
 Grass(){
  pos = new PVector(random(0,width-side),random(0,height-side)); 
 }
 
 void update(){
  age++;
 }
 
 boolean find(){
  if(isEaten)
    return true;
  for(Rabbit r : R){
   if(pos.dist(r.pos) < side){
    isEaten = true;
    r.hasBeenHungry = 0;
    return true;
   }
  }
  return false;
 }
 
 
 void show(){
  float c = map(age,0,10,100,255);
  fill(0,0+c,0);
  noStroke();
  square(pos.x,pos.y,side);
 }
}
```

Second is the animal class which I wanted to extend to rabbits and foxes (I will add them later).

```
class Animal{
  PVector pos;
  PVector vel;
  boolean isDead;
  int age;
  int gender;
  int max_age;
  float max_speed;
  int hasBeenHungry = 0;
  
  //gender 0 means female and 1 means male;
  
  // update means age in months;
  void update(){
   this.age++;
   hasBeenHungry++;
   if(this.age >= max_age){
    isDead = true; 
   }
   float k = (int)random(10);
   if(k == 0){
    isDead = true; 
   }
   if(hasBeenHungry >= 5){
    isDead = true; 
   }
  }
  
  void move(){
   pos.add(this.vel);
   checkBound();
   //this.vel.mult(0);
  }
  
  void checkBound(){
   if(pos.x < 0 || pos.x > width){
       vel.x *= -1;
   }
   if(pos.y < 0|| pos.y > height){
    vel.y *= -1;
   }
  }
  
}
```

Finally, the Rabbit class (I think the issue is with the target function).

```
class Rabbit extends Animal{
  
  
  Rabbit(){
   pos = new PVector(random(0,width),random(0,height));
   vel = new PVector(2,1);
   int k = (int)(random(0,2));
   this.isDead = false;
   this.gender = k;
   this.max_age = 10;
   this.max_speed = 3;
  }
 
  
  void show(){
   if(this.gender == 0){
    fill(120,0,0 );
   }
   else{
    fill(0,0,120); 
   }
   circle(this.pos.x,this.pos.y,15);
  }
  
  void seperate(){
   float desiredRadius = 30;
   int count = 0;
   PVector c = new PVector(0,0);
   for(Rabbit r : R){
     if(r != this){
      float a = pos.dist(r.pos);
      if(a > 0 && a < desiredRadius){
        PVector diff = PVector.sub(pos, r.pos);
        //diff.normalize();
        diff.div(a);        // Weight by distance
        c.add(diff);
        count++;  
      }
     }
   }
    if (count > 0){
      c.div((float)count);
      vel.add(c);
      vel.normalize();
      vel.mult(max_speed);
    }
  }
  
  PVector target(){
   //Each rabbit eats grass so we could make a greedy approach where the rabbit focuses on the grass closest to it
   PVector mi = new PVector(0,0);
   //int distance =  1000;
   for(Grass g : G){
    float a = this.pos.dist(g.pos);
     if(a < pos.dist(mi)){
      mi = g.pos;
     }
    }
    return mi;
  }
  
  void move(){
   super.move();
   vel = target();
   seperate();
   vel.normalize();
   vel.mult(max_speed);
  }
}
```

P.S I am a beginner so some implementations may not be up to the mark, if you find any such issue please tell me so that I can improve.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is in `target()` which defaults the return value to `origin` (0,0).

Therefore, if a `Rabbit` is closer to `origin` than any `Grass` (initially or at any time) it will *always* head to origin.

So this code below corrects for that by targeting the closest `Grass` **unless** there is no `Grass` left in which case it targets `origin`.
I'll make some assumptions:

1. If there is any `Grass` remaining a `Rabbit` should target the closest `Grass`.
2. If there is no `Grass` remaining a `Rabbit` should head to origin (or home).

Then alter your `target` class as such:

```
PVector target(){
    //Each rabbit eats grass so we could make a greedy approach where the rabbit focuses on the grass closest to it
    if (G.isEmpty()) {
        // no more grass - head to origin
        return new PVector(0,0);
    }
    PVector mi = G.get(0).pos;
    for(Grass g : G){
       float a = this.pos.dist(g.pos);

       // this can be optimized by retaining the distance to the current `mi` rather
       // than recalculating it (this was not done).
       if(a < pos.dist(mi)) {
           mi = g.pos;
       }
    }
    // return a new PVector with the selected grass position.
    return new PVector(mi.x,mi.y);
}
```

Also your velocity calculation (which uses `target`) needs some work. It uses the result of `target` which is a position as a velocity - this likely results in instantaneous travel.

To avoid creating lots of garbage `PVectors` you should alter `target()` to pass in a `PVector` reference as in :

```
PVector target(PVector p) {
    // and the return becomes
    p.x = mi.x;
    p.y = mi.y;
    return p;
}
```

And the invocation comes:

```
vel = target(vel);
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply I tried implementing what you said and it helped but a new issue has arisen, the positions of the grass object change even though I do not change it's position, could you please check my mistake.

Comment: Updated the code (the `return` statement) - it is because the code returns the `Grass` PVector (which is then modified later apparently) - so simply create a new `PVector` from the selection position.